# Kendo Scheduler same start and end date for all day event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I want to make start date and end date same for [Kendo UI Scheduler](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler) when All day event set to false. I tried this on edit:

```
edit: function (e) {
    e.event.set("isAllDay", false);
    a = e.event.start;
    a.setHours(a.getHours() + 1)
    e.event.set("end", new Date(a));
}
```

But it is not making end same as start. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this: `a.setHours(a.getHours() + 1)`, which is setting the end date an hour later than the start date.

This works for me:

```
edit: function (e) {
    e.event.set("isAllDay", false);
    var a = e.event.start;
    a.setHours(a.getHours());
    e.event.set("end", new Date(a));
}
```

You can use less code too:

```
edit: function (e) {
    e.event.set("isAllDay", false);
    e.event.set("end", e.event.start);
}
```

Comment: thanks. It worked. Just one issue if I check All Day event and again uncheck it, it changes the date... :(

Comment: Yes, because checking All Day sets the time to 12 am.

Comment: Do you know any event for that?

Comment: As far as I can see, there doesn't seem to be one.